# Why python requests.get and requests.head give different HTTP responses (200 vs 302)?

Tags: web, python-requests, web-crawler

Here is the code:

```
requests.get('https://www.tng-project.org/api/TNG50-1/snapshots/99/subhalos/503437/cutout.hdf5', params = {'stars':'Masses'}, headers={"api-key":"7d595e082708acc270489c7c78dbcc53"})
```

Here I get result: `<Response [200]>`.

But if I replace the `requests.get` with `requests.head`, as below:

```
requests.head('https://www.tng-project.org/api/TNG50-1/snapshots/99/subhalos/503437/cutout.hdf5', params = {'stars':'Masses'}, headers={"api-key":"7d595e082708acc270489c7c78dbcc53"})
```

I get result `<Response [302]>`, which means I cannot obtain any meaningful info from this command line.

How can the same code for `requests.get` and `requests.head` give different results?

Is it possible that I get `<Response [200]>` for `requests.head`? Because I would like to read the headers without downloading the file.

Comment: Servers are free to respond to `GET` and `HEAD` requests differently if they choose to do so.  Most servers don't, but why this server might be doing so is something that can only be answered by the website administrators for that site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default `requests` follows redirects, but `requests.head` specifically doesn't:

> **`requests.head`**
> `**kwargs` – Optional arguments that request takes. If `allow_redirects` is not provided, it will be set to `False` (as opposed to the default request behavior).
>
> https://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/api/#requests.head

So, either figure out if there's a canonical URL which you can hit directly without redirect, or pass `allow_redirects=True`.